# Invalid option name in CATS SAS function?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro where I would like to create a dataset name and then export that dataset to a csv file.

```
%macro export(outputDataset, prefix, outputFileName);
%let dName = cats(&prefix, test);
%let dName2 = cats(&prefix, test2);

data &outputDataset;
     set &dName &dName2;
run;


proc export data=&outputDataset outfile="outputDir/&outputFileName" replace; run;
%mend export;
```

However, when I call the macro using

```
%export(retain, hh_dpt, retained.csv)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid option name hh_dept.
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%let dName = cats(&prefix, test);` stores the string `cats(hh_dpt, test)` into the macro variable `dName`. When the Data Step compiles, SAS sees:

```
data retain
    set cats(hh_dept, test) cats(hh_dept, test2);
run;
```

Which is an invalid use of the `cats` function. You cannot use SAS functions to concatenate dataset names in the Data Step `set` statement.  You can correct this as such:

```
data retain;
     set &prefix.test &prefix.test2;
run;
```

OR

```
%let dName = &prefix.test;
%let dName2 = &prefix.test2;

data retain;
     set &dName &dName2;
run;
```

Where `&prefix` is ended by a `.` to denote that the string `prefix` is the name of the macro variable to be resolved. Without the `.`, the word scanner would assume that the full name of your macro variable is `&prefixtest`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this based on your codes.

```
%macro export(outputDataset, prefix, outputFileName);
%let dName =%sysfunc(catx(.,&prefix, test));
%let dName2 =%sysfunc(catx(.,&prefix, test2));
data &outputDataset;
     set &dName &dName2;
run;
proc export data=&outputDataset outfile="outputDir/&outputFileName" replace; run;
%mend export;

%export(retain, hh_dpt, retained.csv)
```

Comment: Don't call CAT() functions to string together macro variable values. Just reference them where you want them.  `&prefix.test`